# Conditional AJAX confirm with a new value in Wicket

Tags: ajax, conditional-statements, wicket, onchange

I need to solve a simple problem, but yet I have not been able to found out any solution yet.

I have a simple DropDownChoice with AJAX onChange() JS event. I need to add a confirm box before the onUpdate() action is done - this is not difficult, BUT I need to display the confirm box only if the new selected value of the DropDownChoice is X (one certain value), and do not display the confirm box in any other case. Is it doable?

Short example snippet:

```
DropDownChoice<Integer> choice = new DropDownChoice<Integer>("id", new Model<Integer>(0));
choice.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      // do some stuff
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes) {
        super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.getAjaxCallListeners().add(new AjaxCallListener() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPrecondition(Component component) {
                return "return confirm('Really?')"; // I NEED THIS DISPLAYED CONDITIONALLY
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know how to access the "choice" model object (converted input...) with the proposed value to add it to a condition in updateAjaxAttributes() method.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go for a JavaScript-based solution. The code of AJAX call listener is executed in a scope where you can use variable attrs. This variable contains the parameters used to perform AJAX call, including the id of the component. In this way you could check for selected value.

See more at http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/ajax.html#ajax_5